# so I was trying to make a code that changes the writings font(arial,times new roman etc.) in the textbox every 750 miliseconds but I couldn't do it

Tags: c#, button, fonts, textbox

```cs
private void OnTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    i += 1;
}
```

I tried to make the timer

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    FontFamily[] fontlar = FontFamily.Families;
    fontlar.GetUpperBound(i);

    Timer timer1 = new Timer
    {
        Interval = 750
    };
    timer1.Enabled = true;
    timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(OnTimer);
}
```

I put the code in form1 but I tried it in textbox as well it didn't work

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are new to this.

1. Your Timer does nothing
2. Your Timer is local, it should be public
3. You didn't create your Textbox

I think this would be your answer:

```
 Timer timer1;
    int i = 0;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1 = new Timer
        {
            Interval = 750
        };
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(OnTimer);
    }
    private void OnTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        i += 1;
        FontFamily[] fontlar = FontFamily.Families;
        //fontlar.GetUpperBound(i);
        textBox1.Font = new Font(fontlar[i], 16.0f);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Don't forget to create a textbox on your form.

Comment: You can handle the exception when the iterator "i" is greater than or equal to the fontlar length by changing `i += 1` to `i = (i + 1) % fontlar.Length;`